Visualization and interpretation GAM three-way interaction (2 continuous, 1 categorical variable)
I'm relatively new with gams, yet handling a complex dataset.I've gone over some of the previous questions on related topics and have made some progress in understanding the interaction with GAM, but I still need some help to understand my results and make sure my modeling approach is statistically sound. I use mgcv in R.
Background
I collected data from an experiment in which participants received feedback from others (feedback; Categorical variables (like,dislike,ambiguous)), at the same time, I recorded the EEG signal of the subjects when they received the evaluation from others (continuous variable; FRN_C). After that, subjects were also asked to rate others (continuous variable; likerating.resp_wins). The hypothesis of my research is that the personality traits of the subjects will affect their evaluation to others after receiving the evaluation from others. Thus, another independent variable is personality trait (continuous variable; AnxietyC).
I was interested in personality traits, feedback type, and whether the EEG signals of different feedback could predict subjects' evaluations to others. So I model fit these variables.
rating.gam <-gamm(likerating.resp_wins ~ feedback + te(AnxietyC, FRN_C, by = feedback) + s(AvoidC), 
                     random=list(subID=~1),data=cleaned_data, na.action = na.omit)

the results as follow:
> anova(peak.r.int.gam$gam)

Family: gaussian 
Link function: identity 

Formula:
likerating.resp_wins ~ te(AnxietyC, FRN_C, by = feedback) + s(AvoidC)

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                              edf    Ref.df    F        p-value
te(AnxietyC,FRN_C):feedbackambiguous          3.00   3.00      0.585    0.625
te(AnxietyC,FRN_C):feedbackdislike            10.98  10.98     4.862    < 2e-16
te(AnxietyC,FRN_C):feedbacklike               3.00   3.00      7.895    3.12e-05
s(AvoidC)                                     1.00   1.00      0.443    0.506

Q1:
I have some confusion about the interpretation of this result. Could this result mean that AnxietyC and FRN_C can predict participants' ratings of others when they are like and dislike? However, under ambiguous conditions, AnxietyC and FRN_C were unable to predict participants' ratings of others.
Q2:
So next, I want to be able to visualize the outcome of this interaction. Should I split the feedback into dislike and like interactions? Or should I split all three feedback with AnxietyC and FRN_C interact?
Q3:
I also have some doubts about the method of visualizing interactions. I used two different methods to decompose the results of the three factors, but the graphs produced by the two methods are quite different, and I am not sure which method is more reasonable.
I used fvisgam to decompose AnxietyC and FRN_C interactions under three different feedback conditions.
Option1: I did the visualization on the basis of the full model
gamm(likerating.resp_wins ~ feedback + te(AnxietyC, FRN_C, by = feedback) + s(AvoidC), 
                     random=list(subID=~1),data=cleaned_data, na.action = na.omit)

fvisgam(peak.r.int.gam.plot$gam, view=c("AnxietyC", "FRN_C"), cond=list(feedback="dislike"),
        main="dislike",  rm.ranef=TRUE,, xlim =c(35,80),
        labcex=.1, contour.col = "black", add.color.legend = F, lwd = .5,
        color = c("white","steelblue1","black"), show.diff = T, col.diff = "red", alpha.diff=.3, sim.ci=T)

fvisgam(peak.r.int.gam.plot$gam, view=c("AnxietyC", "FRN_C"), cond=list(feedback="ambiguous"),
        main="ambiguous", rm.ranef=TRUE,, xlim =c(35,80),
        labcex=.1, contour.col = "black", add.color.legend = F, lwd = .5,
        color = c("white","steelblue1","black"), show.diff = T, col.diff = "red", alpha.diff=.3, sim.ci=T)

fvisgam(peak.r.int.gam.plot$gam, view=c("AnxietyC", "FRN_C"), cond=list(feedback="like"),
        main="like", rm.ranef=TRUE,, xlim =c(35,80),
        labcex=.1, contour.col = "black", add.color.legend = F, lwd = .5,
        color = c("white","steelblue1","black"), show.diff = T, col.diff = "red", alpha.diff=.3, sim.ci=T)




option2： In the second method, I select three types of feedback data respectively, and then re-fit the model three times, and then visualize it.
feedback_levels <- unique(cleaned_data$feedback)
plots <- list()

for (feedback_type in feedback_levels) {

  subset_data <- cleaned_data[cleaned_data$feedback == feedback_type,]
  
  gam_model <- gamm(likerating.resp_wins ~  te(AnxietyC, FRN_C) + s(avoidC), 
                    random=list(subID=~1), data=subset_data, na.action = na.omit)
  
  plot <- fvisgam(gam_model$gam, view= c("AnxietyC", "FRN_C"), xlim =c(35,80), main=feedback_type, labcex=.1, contour.col = "black", add.color.legend = F, lwd = .5,
color = c("white","steelblue1","black"), show.diff = T, col.diff = "red", alpha.diff=.3, sim.ci=T,)
}




It seems that the picture of the second method is more explicit and more consistent with the hypothesis.  Therefore, I want to know, These two visualization methods are right or wrong? Or which approach is more appropriate?
Thanks a lot for the help!
